# Remove prefixed attribute in scala (scala-xml)

Tags: xml, scala, scala-xml

I am trying to remove an attribute with prefix in Scala using a RuleTransformer.

While the following works with unprefixed attributes:

```
val xml = <foo><bar attr="attval">content</bar></foo>
val rw1 = new RewriteRule {
  override def transform(n: Node) = n match {
    case Elem(null, "bar", a, s, children @ _*) =>
      Elem(null, "bar", a.remove("attr"), TopScope, children: _*)
    case x => x
  }
}
val rt = new RuleTransformer(rw1)
rt(xml)
```

I do not succeed doing this with a prefixed attribute (note that attribute "attr" of the "bar" element has the prefix "pre"):

```
val xml = <foo><bar pre:attr="attval">content</bar></foo>
val rw1 = new RewriteRule {
  override def transform(n: Node) = n match {
    case Elem(null, "bar", a, s, children @ _*) =>
      Elem(null, "bar", a.remove("attr"), TopScope, children: _*)
    case x => x
  }
}
val rt = new RuleTransformer(rw1)
rt(xml)
```

I was trying to use

```
a.remove("pref",TopScope,"attr")
```

as defined by

```
MetaData.remove(namespace: String, scope: NamespaceBinding, key: String)
```

without any success.

I am a Scala beginner, so bear with me if this is a trivial issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't remove a prefixed attribute with `remove(String)` because of its implementation:

From `Attribute.scala`:

```
def remove(key: String) =
  if (!isPrefixed && this.key == key) next
  else copy(next remove key)
```

As you can see, if the attribute is prefixed, the first branch condition is false. However, there is a different function in the same class:

```
def remove(namespace: String, scope: NamespaceBinding, key: String) =
  if (this.key == key && (scope getURI pre) == namespace) next
  else copy(next.remove(namespace, scope, key))
```

where the branch succeeds only if `scope.getURI(pre) == namespace`, where `pre` is the prefix, in your example `"pre"`.

The implementation of `scope.getURI` belongs to `NamespaceBinding.scala`:

```
def getURI(_prefix: String): String =
  if (prefix == _prefix) uri 
  else parent getURI _prefix
```

where all three, `prefix`, `uri`, and `parent` are fields of the class. So in your example, `prefix` must be `"pre"`, `uri` must be the string value of `namespace` which is the first argument to `remove`, and `parent` must not be null, if you do not want exceptions to happen.

I do not know much about xml namespaces, but I assume you would need to have the appropriate values if your XML is well defined. If you would want to artificially craft some suitable values **for this example**, you could do the following (in your `transform`-method):

```
case Elem(null, "bar", a, s, children @ _*) =>
  val scope = n.scope.copy(prefix = "pre", uri = "pre", parent = n.scope)
  Elem(null, "bar", a.remove("pre", scope, "attr"), TopScope, minimizeEmpty = true, children: _*)
```

Note that I set `parent` to `n.scope`, which in your example is the top-scope.

A small side-note: the `apply`-method of `Elem` that you use is deprecated since Scala 2.10, so I changed it to the non-deprecated method by setting `minimizeEmpty` to `true`.

Answer (score 2):

Just to provide the way how I was able to do the mentioned example thanks to the useful hints given here:

```
val xml = <foo><bar pre:attr="attval">content</bar></foo>
val rw1 = new RewriteRule {
    override def transform(n: Node) = n match {
      case Elem(null, "bar", _, _, _) =>
        n.asInstanceOf[Elem].copy(attributes = new UnprefixedAttribute("attr", "attval", Null))
    case x => x
  }
}  
val rt = new RuleTransformer(rw1)
rt(xml)
```

Result:

```
result: scala.xml.Node = <foo><bar attr="attval">content</bar></foo>
```

Comment: Removing the prefix is definitively also a solution. If you do not care about the prefix at all, I'd suggest the following generalization: `attributes = a.toList.reverse.foldLeft[MetaData](Null)((next, current) => new UnprefixedAttribute(current.key, current.value, next))` which removes all prefixes, but keeps the attributes the same otherwise. Since everything is immutable, you won't have any bad sideeffects. Conversion to `List` is necessary, because `UnprefixedAttribute` is designed to hold the pointer to the next element itself.

Comment: By the way: If you do not care about some values in your match clause, you can simply use an underscore and don't have to pollute your code with variables. In your code, `case e @ Elem(null, "bar", _, _, _) =>` would match the same. Also, you do not need to add `e @ Elem...`, since `e` here is the same object as `n`, so you could simply cast `n.asInstanceOf[Elem]` instead.